# How to make my Current EXP integer not reset to 0 after reloading

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

***UPDATE***
Here is the video showing the bugs. 
https://youtu.be/R3r-Y2jsxps

I'm trying to develop a tycoon style game however I'm having a few bugs. I just finished coding the autosave and I'm having 2 problems. The scripts that auto the integers higher, stop and reset. and my current exp level stays but the current exp doesn't save.

Code (expScipt)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class expScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //Current level
    public static int vLevel = 1;

    //Current exp amount
    public static int vCurrExp = 0;

    //Exp amount needed for lvl 1
    public static int vExpBase = 25;

    //Exp amount left to next levelup
    public static int vExpLeft = 25;

    //Modifier that increases needed exp each level
    public float vExpMod = 1.15f;

    public Slider ExpBar;
    public Text displayText;
    public Text LevelDisplayText;
    public static int currentValue = 0;

    public int CurrentValuee
    {
       get { return currentValue; }
       set
       {
           currentValue = value;
           ExpBar.value = currentValue;
           ExpBar.maxValue = vExpLeft;
       }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        displayText.GetComponent<Text>().text = (ExpBar.value) + " EXP";
        LevelDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Level : " + vLevel;
        currentValue = vCurrExp;

        if (vCurrExp == vExpLeft)
        {
           ExpBar.value = 0;
           displayText.GetComponent<Text>().text = (ExpBar.value) + " EXP";
        }
    }

    public void ExpPlusOne()
    {
        CurrentValuee += 1;
    }

    //Leveling methods
    public void GainExp(int e)
    {
        vCurrExp += e;

        if(vCurrExp >= vExpLeft)
        {
           LvlUp();
        }
    }

    void LvlUp()
    {
        vCurrExp -= vExpLeft;
        vLevel++;
        float t = Mathf.Pow(vExpMod, vLevel);
        vExpLeft = (int)Mathf.Floor(vExpBase * t);
    }
}
```

and the saving script below,

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GlobalGameMechanics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource muffinSound;
    public static double GlobalPlayerDiamonds;
    public static double InternalPlayerDiamonds = 1500000;
    public GameObject PlayerDiamondDisplay;
    public static double InternalPlayerMuffins = 0;
    public static double TotalMPSint = 0;
    public double Test = 0;
    public static double currentMuffins;
    public GameObject ShopPanel;
    public GameObject DiamondShop;
    public Text MuffinText;
    public Text TotalMPS;

    public void Start()
    {
      Load();
    }
    void Update()
    {

       GlobalPlayerDiamonds = InternalPlayerDiamonds;
       PlayerDiamondDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + InternalPlayerDiamonds;
       MuffinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Muffins " + InternalPlayerMuffins;
       TotalMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "MPS: " + TotalMPSint;

       TotalMPSint = (GlobalBakery.BakeryMPSint + GlobalFactory.FactoryMPSint + GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinMPSint + GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandMPSint + GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryMPSint + GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmMPSint + GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityMPSint + GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsMPSint + GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2MPSint + GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinMPSint + GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinMPSint + GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinMPSint +  GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinMPSint + GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinMPSint +  GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2Levelint);

       GlobalMuffins.MuffinCount = InternalPlayerMuffins;
       currentMuffins = InternalPlayerMuffins;

       if (InternalPlayerMuffins > 10000)
       {
         MuffinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Muffins " + (InternalPlayerMuffins / 1000).ToString("0.00") + "k";
       }
       if (TotalMPSint >= 10000) 
        {
         TotalMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "/Sec " + (TotalMPSint / 1000).ToString("0.00") + "k";
        }
       if (InternalPlayerMuffins >= 1000000)
       {
         MuffinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Muffins " + (InternalPlayerMuffins / 1000000).ToString("0.00") + "M";
       }
       if (TotalMPSint >= 1000000) 
        {
         TotalMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "/Sec " + (TotalMPSint / 1000000).ToString("0.00") + "M";
        }
        if (InternalPlayerMuffins >= 1000000000)
       {
         MuffinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Muffins " + (InternalPlayerMuffins / 1000000000).ToString("0.00") + "B";
       }
       if (TotalMPSint >= 1000000000) 
        {
         TotalMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "/Sec " + (TotalMPSint / 1000000000).ToString("0.00") + "B";
        }
       if (InternalPlayerMuffins >= 1000000000000)
       {
         MuffinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Muffins " + (InternalPlayerMuffins / 1000000000000).ToString("0.00") + "T";
       }
        if (TotalMPSint >= 1000000000000) 
        {
         TotalMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "/Sec " + (TotalMPSint / 1000000000000).ToString("0.00") + "T";
        }
       if (InternalPlayerMuffins >= 1000000000000000)
       {
         MuffinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Muffins " + (InternalPlayerMuffins / 1000000000000000).ToString("0.00") + "Qa";
       }
      if (TotalMPSint >= 1000000000000000) 
        {
         TotalMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "/Sec " + (TotalMPSint / 1000000000000000).ToString("0.00") + "Qa";
        }
       if (InternalPlayerMuffins >= 1000000000000000000)
       {
         MuffinText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Muffins " + (InternalPlayerMuffins / 1000000000000000000).ToString("0.00") + "Qi";
       }
       if (TotalMPSint >= 1000000000000000000) 
        {
         TotalMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "/Sec " + (TotalMPSint / 1000000000000000000).ToString("0.00") + "Qi";
        }

    Save();

     }

       public void muffinonClick()
        {
           muffinSound.Play();
           InternalPlayerMuffins += (1 + GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickInt );
        }
        public void OpenShop()
        {
            if(ShopPanel != null){
                ShopPanel.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("PanelAnimFadeOpen");
                Debug.Log("playing anim");
                ShopPanel.SetActive(true);}  
        }
        public void OpenDiamondShop()
        {
            if(DiamondShop != null){
                DiamondShop.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("PanelAnimFadeOpen");
                Debug.Log("playing anim");
                DiamondShop.SetActive(true);}  
        }
public void Load()
{
GlobalPlayerDiamonds = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPlayerDiamonds","0"));
InternalPlayerDiamonds = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("InternalPlayerDiamonds","150000"));
InternalPlayerMuffins = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("InternalPlayerMuffins","0"));
TotalMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("TotalMPSint","0"));
currentMuffins = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("currentMuffins","0"));
GlobalBakery.BakeryCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBakery.BakeryCostint","25"));
GlobalBakery.BakeryDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBakery.BakeryDiamondCostint","1"));
GlobalBakery.BakeryLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBakery.BakeryLevelint","0"));
GlobalBakery.BakeryMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBakery.BakeryMPSint","0"));
GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinCostint","500000000"));
GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinDiamondCostint","10"));
GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinLevelint","0"));
GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinMPSint","0"));
GlobalFactory.FactoryCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalFactory.FactoryCostint","125"));
GlobalFactory.FactoryDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalFactory.FactoryDiamondCostint","2"));
GlobalFactory.FactoryLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalFactory.FactoryLevelint","0"));
GlobalFactory.FactoryMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalFactory.FactoryMPSint","0"));
GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinCostint","2500000000000"));
GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinDiamondCostint","14"));
GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinLevelint","0"));
GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinMPSint","0"));
GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityCostint","12500"));
GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityDiamondCostint","7"));
GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityLevelint","0"));
GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityMPSint","0"));
GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmCostint","2500"));
GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmDiamondCostint","6"));
GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmLevelint","0"));
GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmMPSint","0"));
GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsCostint","25000"));
GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsDiamondCostint","8"));
GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsLevelint","0"));
GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsMPSint","0"));
GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2Costint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2Costint","25000000"));
GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2DiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2DiamondCostint","9"));
GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2Levelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2Levelint","0"));
GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2MPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2MPSint","0"));
GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandCostint","750"));
GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandDiamondCostint","4"));
GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandLevelint","0"));
GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandMPSint","0"));
GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinCostint","75000000000"));
GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinDiamondCostint","11"));
GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinLevelint","0"));
GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinMPSint","0"));
GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinCostint","150000000000"));
GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinDiamondCostint","12"));
GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinLevelint","0"));
GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinMPSint","0"));
GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickInt = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickInt","2"));
GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickCostint","5000"));
GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickDiamondCostint","5"));
GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickLevelint","1"));
GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickMultiplierint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickMultiplierint","2"));
GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinCostint","250"));
GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinDiamondCostint","3"));
GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinLevelint","0"));
GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinMPSint","0"));
GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryCostint","1500"));
GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryDiamondCostint","5"));
GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryLevelint","0"));
GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryMPSint","0"));
GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinCostint","500000000000"));
GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinDiamondCostint","13"));
GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinLevelint","0"));
GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinMPSint","0"));

  expScript.vLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("expScript.vLevel", 1);
  expScript.vCurrExp = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("expScript.vCurrExp", 0);
  expScript.vExpBase = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("expScript.vExpBase", 10);
  expScript.vExpLeft = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("expScript.vExpLeft", 25);
  expScript.currentValue = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("expScript.currentValue", 0);
}
```

Auto MPS Scripts

Bakery

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GlobalBakery : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool turnOffButton = false;
    public AudioSource playSound;
    public GameObject BakeryCost;
    public GameObject BakeryLevel;
    public GameObject BakeryMPS;
    public GameObject BakeryButton;
    public GameObject FakeBakeryButton;
    public static double BakeryCostint = 25;
    public static double BakeryDiamondCostint = 1;
    public static double BakeryLevelint = 0;
    public static double BakeryMPSint;
    public GameObject FakeBakeryCost;
    public GameObject FakeBakeryLevel;
    public GameObject FakeBakeryMPS;
    public GameObject BakeryDiamondCost;
    public GameObject FakeBakeryDiamondCost;
    public GameObject MaxLevelDiamondButton;
    public GameObject MaxLevelBakeryCost;
    public GameObject MaxLevelBakeryLevel;
    public GameObject MaxLevelFakeBakeryMPS;
    public GameObject MaxLevelBakeryButtom;
    void Update()
    {
        BakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost: " + BakeryCostint;
        BakeryLevel.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Level: " + BakeryLevelint;
        BakeryMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "MPS: " + BakeryMPSint;
        BakeryDiamondCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = BakeryDiamondCostint + " Diamond";

        FakeBakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost: " + BakeryCostint;
        FakeBakeryLevel.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Level: " + BakeryLevelint;
        FakeBakeryMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "MPS: " + BakeryMPSint;
        FakeBakeryDiamondCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = BakeryDiamondCostint + " Diamond";

        MaxLevelBakeryLevel.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Level: " + BakeryLevelint;
        MaxLevelFakeBakeryMPS.GetComponent<Text>().text = "MPS: " + BakeryMPSint;

        if(GlobalGameMechanics.currentMuffins >= BakeryCostint)
        {
            FakeBakeryButton.SetActive(false);
            BakeryButton.SetActive(true);
        }
        if(turnOffButton == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Turning off");
               FakeBakeryButton.SetActive(true);
               BakeryButton.SetActive(false);
                turnOffButton = false;
            }
            if(GlobalGameMechanics.currentMuffins <= BakeryCostint)
        {
            FakeBakeryButton.SetActive(true);
            BakeryButton.SetActive(false);
        }

             if (BakeryCostint >= 10000)
       {
         BakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 1000).ToString("0.0") + "k";
         FakeBakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 1000).ToString("0.0") + "k";
       }
       if (BakeryCostint > 1000000)
       {
         BakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 1000000).ToString("0.0") + "M";
         FakeBakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 1000000).ToString("0.0") + "M";
       }
        if (BakeryCostint > 1000000000)
       {
         BakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 1000000000).ToString("0.0") + "B";
         FakeBakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 1000000000).ToString("0.0") + "B";
       }
       if (BakeryCostint > 1000000000000)
       {
         BakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 1000000000000).ToString("0.0") + "T";
         FakeBakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 1000000000000).ToString("0.0") + "T";
       }
        if (BakeryCostint > 1000000000000000)
       {
         BakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 1000000000000000).ToString("0.0") + "Qa";
         FakeBakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 1000000000000000).ToString("0.0") + "Qa";
       }
       if (BakeryCostint > 1000000000000000000)
       {
         BakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 1000000000000000000).ToString("0.0") + "Qi";
         FakeBakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (BakeryCostint / 10000000000000000).ToString("0.0") + "Qi";
       }

       if (BakeryLevelint >= 9999)
       {
           BakeryCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "MAX LEVEL";
           BakeryButton.SetActive(false);
           FakeBakeryButton.SetActive(false);
           BakeryDiamondCost.SetActive(false);
           FakeBakeryDiamondCost.SetActive(false);
           MaxLevelDiamondButton.SetActive(false);
           MaxLevelBakeryButtom.SetActive(true);
       }

    }
    public void StartAutoBakery()
    {
        if (GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerMuffins >=BakeryCostint){
        playSound.Play();
        InvokeRepeating("muffinonClick", 0f, 1.0f);
        GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerMuffins -= BakeryCostint;

        BakeryCostint += 5;
        turnOffButton = true;
        Debug.Log("Button Turned Off");
        BakeryMPSint += 1;
        BakeryLevelint += 1;
        }else{
            Debug.Log("Cant do anything");
        }
    }
    public void PurchaseBakeryWithDiamonds()
    {
        if (GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerDiamonds >=BakeryDiamondCostint){
        playSound.Play();
        InvokeRepeating("muffinonClick", 0f, 1.0f);
        GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerDiamonds -= BakeryDiamondCostint;
        BakeryCostint += 5;
        turnOffButton = true;
        BakeryMPSint += 1;
        BakeryLevelint += 1;
        }else{
            Debug.Log("You Dont Have Enough Diamonds");
        }
    }
    public void muffinonClick()
        {
           GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerMuffins += 1;
        }
}
```

Power Click Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GlobalPowerClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool turnOffButton = false;
    public AudioSource playSound;
    public GameObject PowerClickCost;
    public GameObject PowerClickLevel;
    public GameObject PowerClickMultiplier;
    public GameObject PowerClickButton;
    public GameObject FakePowerClickButton;
    public static double PowerClickInt = 2;
    public static double PowerClickCostint = 5000;
    public static double PowerClickDiamondCostint = 5;
    public static double PowerClickLevelint = 1;
    public static double PowerClickMultiplierint = 2;
    public GameObject FakePowerClickCost;
    public GameObject FakePowerClickLevel;
    public GameObject FakePowerClickMultiplier;
    public GameObject PowerClickDiamondCost;
    public GameObject FakePowerClickDiamondCost;
    public GameObject MaxLevelDiamondButton;
    public GameObject MaxLevelPowerClickCost;
    public GameObject MaxLevelPowerClickLevel;
    public GameObject MaxLevelFakePowerClickMultiplier;
    public GameObject MaxLevelPowerClickButtom;

    void Update()
    {
        PowerClickCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost: " + PowerClickCostint;
        PowerClickLevel.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Level: " + PowerClickLevelint;
        PowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = "x" + PowerClickMultiplierint + " Multiplier";
        PowerClickDiamondCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = PowerClickDiamondCostint + " Diamonds";

        FakePowerClickCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost: " + PowerClickCostint;
        FakePowerClickLevel.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Level: " + PowerClickLevelint;
        FakePowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = "x" + PowerClickMultiplierint + " Multiplier";
        FakePowerClickDiamondCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = PowerClickDiamondCostint + " Diamonds";

        MaxLevelPowerClickLevel.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Level: " + PowerClickLevelint;
        MaxLevelFakePowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = "x" + PowerClickMultiplierint + " Multiplier";

        if(GlobalGameMechanics.currentMuffins >= PowerClickCostint)
        {
            FakePowerClickButton.SetActive(false);
            PowerClickButton.SetActive(true);
        }
        if(turnOffButton == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Turning off");
               FakePowerClickButton.SetActive(true);
               PowerClickButton.SetActive(false);
                turnOffButton = false;
            }
            if(GlobalGameMechanics.currentMuffins <= PowerClickCostint)
        {
            FakePowerClickButton.SetActive(true);
            PowerClickButton.SetActive(false);
        }

    if (PowerClickCostint >= 10000)
       {
         PowerClickCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (PowerClickCostint / 1000).ToString("0.0") + "k";
         FakePowerClickCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (PowerClickCostint / 1000).ToString("0.0") + "k";
       }
    if (PowerClickMultiplierint >= 10000)
    {
         PowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = " Multiplier " + (PowerClickMultiplierint / 1000).ToString("0.0") + "k";
         FakePowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = " Multiplier " + (PowerClickMultiplierint / 1000).ToString("0.0") + "k";
    }
       if (PowerClickCostint > 1000000)
       {
         PowerClickCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (PowerClickCostint / 1000000).ToString("0.0") + "M";
         FakePowerClickCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (PowerClickCostint / 1000000).ToString("0.0") + "M";
       }
    if (PowerClickMultiplierint > 1000000)
        {
         PowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = " Multiplier " + (PowerClickMultiplierint / 1000000).ToString("0.0") + "M";
         FakePowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = " Multiplier " + (PowerClickMultiplierint / 1000000).ToString("0.0") + "M";
         MaxLevelFakePowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = " Multiplier " + (PowerClickMultiplierint / 1000000).ToString("0.0") + "M";
        }
        if (PowerClickCostint > 1000000000)
       {
         PowerClickCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (PowerClickCostint / 1000000000).ToString("0.0") + "B";
         FakePowerClickCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (PowerClickCostint / 1000000000).ToString("0.0") + "B";
         MaxLevelFakePowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Multiplier " + (PowerClickCostint / 1000000000).ToString("0.0") + "B";
       }
       if (PowerClickMultiplierint > 1000000000)
       {
         PowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = " Multiplier " + (PowerClickMultiplierint / 1000000000).ToString("0.0") + "B";
         FakePowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = " Multiplier " + (PowerClickMultiplierint / 1000000000).ToString("0.0") + "B";
         MaxLevelFakePowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = " Multiplier " + (PowerClickMultiplierint / 1000000000).ToString("0.0") + "B";
       }
       if (PowerClickCostint > 1000000000000)
       {
         PowerClickCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (PowerClickCostint / 1000000000000).ToString("0.0") + "T";
         FakePowerClickCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cost " + (PowerClickCostint / 1000000000000).ToString("0.0") + "T";
         MaxLevelFakePowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Multiplier " + (PowerClickCostint / 1000000000000).ToString("0.0") + "T";
       }
       if (PowerClickMultiplierint > 1000000000000)
       {
         PowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = " Multiplier " + (PowerClickMultiplierint / 1000000000000).ToString("0.0") + "T";
         FakePowerClickMultiplier.GetComponent<Text>().text = " Multiplier " + (PowerClickMultiplierint / 1000000000000).ToString("0.0") + "T";
       }
       if (PowerClickLevelint >= 40)
       {
           PowerClickCost.GetComponent<Text>().text = "MAX LEVEL";
           PowerClickButton.SetActive(false);
           FakePowerClickButton.SetActive(false);
           PowerClickDiamondCost.SetActive(false);
           FakePowerClickDiamondCost.SetActive(false);
           MaxLevelDiamondButton.SetActive(false);
           MaxLevelPowerClickButtom.SetActive(true);
       }

       }
    public void StartAutoPowerClick()
    {
        if (GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerMuffins >=PowerClickCostint){
        playSound.Play();
        GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerMuffins -= PowerClickCostint;
        PowerClickInt *=1*2;
        PowerClickCostint *=1*2;
        turnOffButton = true;
        Debug.Log("Button Turned Off");
        PowerClickLevelint += 1;
        PowerClickMultiplierint *=1*2;
        }else{
            Debug.Log("Cant do anything");
        }
    }
    public void PurchaseAutoPowerClickWithDiamonds()
    {
        if (GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerDiamonds >=PowerClickDiamondCostint){
        playSound.Play();
        GlobalGameMechanics.InternalPlayerDiamonds -= PowerClickDiamondCostint;
        PowerClickInt *=1*2;
        PowerClickCostint *=1*2;
        PowerClickDiamondCostint +=5;
        turnOffButton = true;
        Debug.Log("Button Turned Off");
        PowerClickLevelint += 1;
        PowerClickMultiplierint *=1*2;
        }else{
            Debug.Log("Cant do anything");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not appropriate to tag this question with [tag:visual-studio]. Also, you've shared the **loading** script. You haven't shared the saving script here. Please also share the saving script. It likely includes `PlayerPrefs.SetInt`.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the rest.

Comment: Your update script can be shortened by looping over powers of 10.  Also, I like the idea that the player can have millions of delicious muffins.

Comment: @Amy don't forget the list of unit abbreviations to iterate through.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with this, looks like the cause of the problem might be elsewhere. Can you reproduce this in a completely new scene with minimal code? A [mre] would help this question greatly.

Comment: @Ruzihm That wouldn't be a separate loop.  The suffix can be determined from the power of 10.

Comment: @Amy yeah, I should've said "to index into" rather than "to iterate through"

Comment: First of all I would use `Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("expScript.vCurrExp", 0);` in the load function. If it prints 0 than its never saved correctly (or actually 0 right now). If its not 0 then the error must be by setting it or later on.

Comment: And just a small tip. Ind the `GainExp` Method you should use `while` instead of `if` Thats because if you need like 10 exp for that lvl and 20 for the next but you get 300 then it would still only lvl up ones.

Comment: I will add more code when I get home from work, also any idea how I can get the scripts that auto when you click a button to work when I reload aswell?

Comment: Sorry for taking a long time to reply. I've been busy at work this weekend. I will post a small video example of the bugs I'm having and post more scripts. I only have the scripts you see referenced in "Global Game Mechanics " for all the muffin tycoon upgrades. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have anything setting the expbar's max or current value when you load. Your `CurrentValuee` setter already does this, so you can just set `CurrentValuee` to itself in `Load`. To do this, however, you'll need a reference to the instance of `expScript`:

```
public class GlobalGameMechanics : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] expScript expScriptInstance;

    // ...

    public void Load()
    {
        GlobalPlayerDiamonds = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPlayerDiamonds","0"));
        InternalPlayerDiamonds = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("InternalPlayerDiamonds","150000"));
        InternalPlayerMuffins = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("InternalPlayerMuffins","0"));
        TotalMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("TotalMPSint","0"));
    currentMuffins = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("currentMuffins","0"));
        GlobalBakery.BakeryCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBakery.BakeryCostint","25"));
        GlobalBakery.BakeryDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBakery.BakeryDiamondCostint","1"));
        GlobalBakery.BakeryLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBakery.BakeryLevelint","0"));
        GlobalBakery.BakeryMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBakery.BakeryMPSint","0"));
        GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinCostint","500000000"));
        GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinDiamondCostint","10"));
        GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinLevelint","0"));
        GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalBioMuffin.BioMuffinMPSint","0"));
        GlobalFactory.FactoryCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalFactory.FactoryCostint","125"));
        GlobalFactory.FactoryDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalFactory.FactoryDiamondCostint","2"));
        GlobalFactory.FactoryLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalFactory.FactoryLevelint","0"));
        GlobalFactory.FactoryMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalFactory.FactoryMPSint","0"));
        GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinCostint","2500000000000"));
        GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinDiamondCostint","14"));
        GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinLevelint","0"));
        GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalGalacticMuffin.GalacticMuffinMPSint","0"));
        GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityCostint","12500"));
        GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityDiamondCostint","7"));
        GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityLevelint","0"));
        GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinCity.MuffinCityMPSint","0"));
        GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmCostint","2500"));
        GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmDiamondCostint","6"));
        GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmLevelint","0"));
        GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinFarm.MuffinFarmMPSint","0"));
        GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsCostint","25000"));
        GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsDiamondCostint","8"));
        GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsLevelint","0"));
        GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabs.MuffinLabsMPSint","0"));
        GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2Costint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2Costint","25000000"));
        GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2DiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2DiamondCostint","9"));
        GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2Levelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2Levelint","0"));
        GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2MPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLabsv2.MuffinLabsv2MPSint","0"));
        GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandCostint","750"));
        GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandDiamondCostint","4"));
        GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandLevelint","0"));
        GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalMuffinLand.MuffinLandMPSint","0"));
        GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinCostint","75000000000"));
        GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinDiamondCostint","11"));
        GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinLevelint","0"));
        GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalNuclearMuffin.NuclearMuffinMPSint","0"));
        GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinCostint","150000000000"));
        GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinDiamondCostint","12"));
        GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinLevelint","0"));
        GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPlanetMuffin.PlanetMuffinMPSint","0"));
        GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickInt = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickInt","2"));
        GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickCostint","5000"));
        GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickDiamondCostint","5"));
        GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickLevelint","1"));
        GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickMultiplierint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalPowerClick.PowerClickMultiplierint","2"));
        GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinCostint","250"));
        GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinDiamondCostint","3"));
        GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinLevelint","0"));
        GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalRoboMuffin.RoboMuffinMPSint","0"));
        GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryCostint","1500"));
        GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryDiamondCostint","5"));
        GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryLevelint","0"));
        GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalSmartFactory.SmartFactoryMPSint","0"));
        GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinCostint","500000000000"));
        GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinDiamondCostint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinDiamondCostint","13"));
        GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinLevelint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinLevelint","0"));
        GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinMPSint = double.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GlobalUniverseMuffin.UniverseMuffinMPSint","0"));

        expScript.vLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("expScript.vLevel", 1);
        expScript.vCurrExp = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("expScript.vCurrExp", 0);
        expScript.vExpBase = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("expScript.vExpBase", 10);
        expScript.vExpLeft = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("expScript.vExpLeft", 25);
        expScript.currentValue = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("expScript.currentValue", 0);
        expScriptInstance.CurrentValuee = expScriptInstance.CurrentValuee;   

    }
```

And then in the inspector, drag the gameobject that has the `expScript` component attached to it into the `expScriptInstance` field of `GlobalGameMechanics`.

Comment: When I added the "expScript.CurrentValuee = CurrentValuee;" to Load unity gives me some errors.  I changed the int to static so I could add it to Load. Assets\Scripts\expScript.cs(27,9): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'expScript.ExpBar' Assets\Scripts\expScript.cs(28,9): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'expScript.ExpBar'
Assets\Scripts\GlobalGameMechanics.cs(185,29): error CS0103: The name 'CurrentValuee' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @VastShadow Oops, leave it as not static. I meant `expScript.CurrentValuee = expScript.CurrentValuee;`.

Comment: bro lmao it wants it static and it cant be static both give errors Assets\Scripts\GlobalGameMechanics.cs(185,3): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'expScript.CurrentValuee'

Comment: @VastShadow true. When I came back, I forgot `expScript` was your class name (usually class names are `CapitalCase` not `camelCase`). You need to give a reference to the instance of `expScript` to `GlobalGameMechanics`. You can assign it in the inspector as my answer now mentions, or you could change `expScript` to a [singleton](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/116009/121653) and get the instance that way, but that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Yes, Thank you! The current exp now saves! However, the thing that is still breaking the game is the auto scripts (All the ones referenced in Global Game Mechanics) Stop aswell on exit and I need them to start and save progress so the Muffins Per Second Match. The MPS Int stays just doesn't keep giving you muffins after exit. (Example) I Buy 2 upgrades (+2 MPS) I start getting the 2 MPS and now on tier 2 of the upgrade. The upgrade stays and costs more to upgrade, Reload and buy 2 More MPS for a total of 4 MPS/s and im only getting the 2MPS from currently loading. Any Ideas?

Comment: @VastShadow There's not enough information in the question to understand how your code does anything about calculating MPS or uses MPS.

Comment: I will add code of the auto scripts my bad. All 11 or 13 scripts for auto are copy and pasted but changed the main word such as (Bakery) script was copied and pasted and CTRL + F to replace all Bakery. So I'll just post like 2 of them. Thank you

Comment: @VastShadow It's because your autobakery works by using `InvokeRepeating`, which doesn't get set up during `Load`. Also, you should reconsider having it work that way. When your player has 10,000 auto bakeries, it will be very inefficient to call `muffinonClick` 10,000 times  (plus whatever the other buildings call) potentially all on the same frame.

Comment: Yeah In another thread I was in, People told me that InvokeRepeating would be the best for this type of game, Is there any other functions that can work better optimized

Comment: You could have one place that increases InternalPlayerMuffins, using invokeRepeating, and it just increases InternalPlayerMuffins by however much mps you have. And you just call the invokeRepeating on that once ever.

Comment: Thank you! I will see what I can code and come back! Thank you for all your help